# Find exact match string that contains a + character

Tags: regex

My URLs look like this:
`www.example.com/historical+locations/london`
and
`www.example.com/special/london`

I want to see if the URL contains a certain format. Below expression works for the occurence of `special`, but the `+` sign in historical locations seems to mess up the matching on that string.
I tried the follow expressions, none of them match...I can't seem to match on a string containing a `+` character

```
Dim urlMatch As Match = Regex.Match("/historical+locations/london",
                 "(^/special|^/\bhistorical+locations\b)/[a-zA-Z]",
                 RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

Dim urlMatch As Match = Regex.Match("/historical+locations/london",
                 "(^/special|^/historical+locations)/[a-zA-Z]",
                 RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

Dim urlMatch As Match = Regex.Match("/historical+locations/london",
                 "(^/special|^/historical+locations$)/[a-zA-Z]",
                 RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: `"^/(special|historical\+locations)/[a-zA-Z]+$"` Make sure to escape `+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must to escape the plus sign on regex `\+`

```
Dim urlMatch As Match = Regex.Match("/historical+locations/london",
                 "(^/special|^/\bhistorical\+locations\b)/[a-zA-Z]",
                 RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the `+` as it is a regex character meaning 1 or more [greedy]

to escape the regex character and make it a static character add a `\` before the `+` like so:
`\+`

so escaping the `/` as well you get (also combining common regex that will speed up your search):

```
Dim urlMatch As Match = Regex.Match("/historical+locations/london",
             "^\/(special|historical\+locations)\/[a-zA-Z]+",
             RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

^\/(special|historical\+locations)\/[a-zA-Z]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/pOWppNMvjJs-F-Of)